# what does printing "%p" do?

Tags: c++, c, linked-list

I have a linked-list. I want to put the current ptr `sBuffer`

each link is :

```
typedef struct{
   SearchContext *context;
   void *history;
   char id[32];
}ContextmenuContext;
```

but instead I'm getting the address of the next link.

I think "%p" is the bug.

what does printing "%p" do?

`snprintf_safe(sBuffer,"%p",((ContextmenuContext*)current)->history);`

Comment: print address, `%p` is a format string to print address, btw typecase to `void*` to use `%p`

Comment: You need to pass a `void*` for `%p` otherwise it's undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Simple I think (hope) a `void const*` would work as well.  But he is passing a `void*`, so that shouldn't be problem.  (And this question  should be labeled C, since it has nothing to do with C++.)

Comment: @JamesKanze ah you're right. I just saw the cast and didn't look at the rest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`%p` is intended to display the pointer address.

see [printf syntax](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/).

Comment: Note that that page contains a number of errors with regards to the types you pass to `printf`, depending on the specifiers.

Comment: See [`printf()` syntax](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html) according to POSIX.

Comment: @ElchononEdelson Posix has several extensions, and using the `printf` of Posix is likely to cause portability problems down the road, when you port to Windows.

Comment: @JamesKanze You'll have problems with `printf()` anyway, when you port to Windows. Doesn't windows discourage all sorts of normal C library functions in favor of proprietary versions? But note that POSIX is strongly aligned with the ISO C standard, and the POSIX documentation is very, _very_ clear about what comes from C and what is an extension.

Comment: @ElchononEdelson Not in favor of proprietary versions, but in favor of those defined in Annex K of the C standard.  This is one case where it is Unix which tries to lock you into their extensions.  (And the format specifiers for `printf` _do_ have significant extensions in Unix.)